# Prevent the HTML page from resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to prevent the html page from moving, resizing while width page is under 1350 px.

Btw on my css code, for the width, height, transformation: translate, i'm using the value vmax , and not px or %. So the min-width maybe doesn't work with it, all of my elements keep resizing because they are using vmax, so they just adapt there size with the window size too.. :(

I tried this but this doesn't work too (I was trying to stop resizing the three white rectangle, tabcmp0, 1 and 2)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
    #tabcmp0 {
        width: 370px;
    }
    #tabcmp1 {
        width: 370px;
    }
    #tabcmp2 {
        width: 370px;
    }
    body {
        max-width: 1350px;
    }
}
```

[Code + preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BizatqN0GkGc7nedoBF?p=preview)

**See [this page](https://www.quora.com/When-using-CSS-how-can-I-prevent-my-DIVs-from-overlapping-when-I-shrink-my-browser) for exemple , when she is less than some px, the page stop from resizing and a scroll bar appear, i want the same result but i don't know how to do it ...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think there is no choice to return `px` model if you want to create a static content there.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1350px) {
  #tabcmp0 {
      width: 370px;
      height:580px;
      left:210px;
  }
  #tabcmp1 {
    width: 370px;
    height:580px;
    left:590px;
  }
  #tabcmp2 {
    width: 370px;
    height:580px;
   left:980px;
  }
  .select_dev {
    width:202.5px;
  }
  body {
    max-width: 1350px;
  }
}
```

i think you should give all exact `px` values instead of dynamic `vmax` values like that for each element like headers, left menu etc...

Comment: Btw i got a question, im trying to stop resizing the top-page but it keep changing his size, why ? @ReadyFreddy